# How can I get qmake on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to install [QtiPlot](http://soft.proindependent.com/qtiplot.html) on Mac OS X, but I can't compile it since qmake isn't known. How can I install qmake on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

[Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) version

```
$ brew install qt
```

Comment: Better than MacPorts!

Comment: If you get `Error: Qt currently requires --HEAD on Mavericks`, run `brew install qt --HEAD` (requires `git`).

Comment: While `qmake` does exist in the Homebrew package, it doesn't appear to be symlinked by default anymore.  Try `brew link qt`    Or if that doesn't work: `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/qt/<QT_VERSION_HERE>/bin/qmake /usr/local/bin/qmake`

Comment: If you need specific version of `qt`, for example `4.8.7_2`: use `brew switch qt 4.8.7_2`.  Make sure you add it to `PATH`: `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/qt/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: I have installed qt  with Homebrew but I didn't find Qt Maintenance Tool

Comment: @TrinitronX's suggestion is good to use `brew link qt`, but I had to use `--force`. Here's the whole command: `brew link qt --force`. To verify it worked, then run `which qmake` to print out the path to qmake.

Comment: @kbpontius: Thanks!  I've updated the solution to add this information :-)

Answer (score 40):

Just to elaborate for anyone who finds that after installing qt5, can't access **qmake** in the terminal.

Install QT5 using:

```
brew install qt5
```

Then to allow access **qmake** from the terminal you'll need to run:

```
brew link qt5 --force
```

Comment: Perfect, works like charm :)

Answer (score 21):

Just got it!

1. Install MacPorts: http://www.macports.org/
2. On Terminal: `sudo port install qt4-mac`

Then, I got qmake. You can install qtiplot directly by running: `sudo port install qtiplot`. Process takes about 3h.

Comment: It appears that either updating the path, or manually symlinking `qmake` is now needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31318672/1959808

Comment: e.g. /usr/bin/sudo ln -s /opt/local/libexec/qt5/bin/qmake /opt/local/bin/qmake

Answer (score 14):

The official Qt installer, including qmake, is available from nokia at http://qt.nokia.com/downloads, but BE CAREFUL:

The so-called "SDK" download, which appears near the top of the page is **not** what you want.  Maddeningly, qmake and other needed tools are available from the "Qt Libraries" download.  Scroll down the page and find "Qt libraries".  This gets me confused every time I install Qt on the Mac.

Answer (score 7):

`QMake` is part of `Qt` since 3.0, earlier versions had `tMake`.

So, either look for `tMake` instead or install/upgrade your `Qt` to get `QMake`, good luck!

Comment: I don't have Qt installed. I just want to install QtiPlot, but their documentation isn't intuitive.

Comment: You will need the `Qt-devel` and `Qt-config` and their dependencies in order to have `QMake`

Comment: Thanks, do you know any alternative to qmake?

Comment: @FábioPerez: No, QtiPlot is written with the intent that QMake generates the Makefiles.

Answer (score 5):

For installing Qt5 with brew, you can do

> brew install qt5

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as the accepted answer (wouldn't anyone doing the installation recognize a name change and understand to use the actual name of what they want to install)?

Comment: This gave me qt5 but not qmake. I only get qmake with `brew install qt`, but then it is the old version of qmake :(

Comment: worked for me by also doing what suggested by elMarquis

Comment: Can't work out whether it's a synonym in Homebrew, but it does the same thing as `brew install qt`. Today's homebrew recipe doesn't symlink qtmake sadly.

Comment: This absolutely includes `qmake`.  See elMarquis's answer.